# problems setting up admob

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to android scene and wanting to ask a few questions

So far my app is not on play store yet

I set up all the admob essentials

I added to manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
```

added this to main activity

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

also added this to main activity .kt

```
lateinit var mAdView : AdView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
```

but my code is not showing any ad
the test ad works but my real ads not showing

also how do I know if my app is requesting/loading ads?

much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In MobileAds.initialise, you need(this, your key), key as in ca-app-pub-xxxx. Try it and let me know if it works!